# For distributing calculation task, which is better celery or spark

Tags: python, apache-spark, celery, distributed, jobs

Problem: calculation task can be paralleled easily. but it is needed real-time response.

There can be two approaches.
1. using Celery: runs job in parallel from scratch
2. using Spark: runs job in parallel with spark framework

I think spark is better in scalability perspective. But is it OK Spark as backend of web-application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Celery :- is really a good technology for distributed streaming And its supports Python language . Which is it self strong in computation and easy to write. The streaming application in Celery supports so many features as well . Its little over head on CPU.

Spark- Its supports various programming language Java,Scala,Python. its not pure streaming its micro batch streaming as per the Spark documentation

If your task can only be full filled by streaming and you dont need the SQl like feature . Then Celery will be the best. But you need various feature along with streaming then SPark will be better . In that case you can take scenario you application will generate the data in how many batches within second .

Answer (score 2):

Adding to the above answer, there are other areas also to identify.

1. Integration with the existing big data stack if you have.
2. Data pipeline for ingestion
3. You mentioned "backend for web application". I assume its for read operation. The response times for any batch application might not be a good fit for any web application.

Choice of streaming can help you get the data into the cluster faster. But it will not guarantee the response times needed for web app. You need to look at HBase and Solr(if you are searching).

Spark is undoubtedly better and faster than other batch frameworks. In streaming there may be few other. As I mentioned above, you should consider the parameters on which your choice is made.